# ExtJS 4 creating nodes for TreeStore

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree, extjs4

Im trying to build TreeGrid with ExtJs 4.
I have a servlet, which returns me big object and i want to divide this JSON Data for separate trees and display them on different Ext.Tree.Panels.
I dont want to have multiple queries for server side to get data for each tree, because logically its one object.
Object looks like this.

```
root : {
 ...
 some_meta_data_fields here..
 ..
 tree1 :{ 
  a : {
     data:..
     children: [..]
   },
  b : {
     data:..
     children: [..]
   }
  ...more childs here...
 },
 tree2 : {
  ..another tree...
 }
}
```

So, tree1 is for one Tree.Panel and tree2 for another, and all synchronization with server should be centralized.

I obtained data from server like Ext.Ajax(..) and created different Tree.Store with different root param like:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                model: 'model',
                root : root.tree1,
                proxy  : {
                   type: 'memory',
                   ....JSON reader and other.
                 }
                }
             });
```

But when such store loads is transforms original object(detach leafs for exapmle) and this is unacceptable.
I think i should fill tree store manually like this:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
             root : {name: "proxyRoot"},
            model: 'model',
            load : function(node){
                var that = this;

                Ext.each(a.children, function(child, index) {


                    var node = that.getRootNode().appendChild({
                            name : child.name,
                            val : child.val
                        });
                        Ext.each(node.children, function(leaf, index) {
                            node.appendChild({
                                name : leaf.name,
                                val : leaf.val
                            });
                        })
                    });
                    console.log(that);

                }
             });
```

After tree loads it shows only root which cant be expanded, but in console i can see that data is loaded correctly and i have desired hierarchy in ExtJs store object.
Im really stuck with this problem, but its totally unacceptable for me to make different queries for each tree.
I will be very happy if someone can could point me to solution.
Thanks.